# Mysql LIMIT OFFSET error using python

Tags: python, mysql, pagination, limit

I am working on python and tried to fetch some data from Mysql Database and following  is the query

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
page  = 1
perpage = 3
offset = (int(page) - 1) * perpage
conn = mdb.connect(user='root', passwd='redhat', db='Python_Web', host='localhost')
cursor_posts = conn.cursor()
posts = "select * from projects LIMIT = %s OFFSET = %s " %(offset,perpage)
cursor_posts.execute(posts)
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/ultraTB.py", line 667, in text
    locals,formatvalue=var_repr))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/inspect.py", line 885, in formatargvalues
    specs.append(strseq(args[i], convert, join))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/inspect.py", line 840, in strseq
    return convert(object)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/inspect.py", line 882, in convert
    return formatarg(name) + formatvalue(locals[name])
KeyError: 'connection'

IPython's exception reporting continues...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/local/user/python_webcode/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.pyc in execute(self, query, args)
    172             del tb
    173             self.messages.append((exc, value))
--> 174             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
    175         self._executed = query
    176         if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.pyc in defaulterrorhandler(***failed resolving arguments***)
     34     del cursor
     35     del connection
---> 36     raise errorclass, errorvalue
     37 
     38 re_numeric_part = re.compile(r"^(\d+)")

ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 0 OFFSET = 3' at line 1")
```

Can anyone let me know whats wrong in my query above,
actually i am trying to achieve pagination in python using web.py framework

Comment: Yeah, comment already deleted, didn't scroll down far enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I belive this should be just `LIMIT %s OFFSET %s`.  No equal signs.

Answer (score 3):

Neither LIMIT nor OFFSET use `=` equals signs, so your SQL is indeed incorrect.

You really should use SQL parameters, where the database library quotes your values and prevents SQL injection attacks:

```
posts = "select * from projects LIMIT %s OFFSET %s"
cursor_posts.execute(posts, (perpage, offset))
```

Note the order of the parameters as well; `LIMIT` comes first, so pass in your `perpage` parameter first.

You can just use:

```sql
LIMIT %s, %s
posts = "select * from projects LIMIT %s, %s"
cursor_posts.execute(posts, (offset, perpage))
```

as well, replacing `OFFSET` with a comma, and *swapping the arguments*.

Comment: @random_stackoverflow_user: the OP had the parameters reversed, I paid it no specific heed.

Comment: Sorry, revision of my earlier comment. I guess you had reversed the offset and perpage parameters to reflect the OP's params. Instead you can just use the syntax "LIMIT %s, %s" where the first arg is the starting ordered record (offset) and the second is # of records to retrieve (perpage)

Comment: @random_stackoverflow_user: I knew I should've checked the documentation. :-P